# Show/Hide Bitmap in EaselJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, easeljs

I'm trying to hide/show a Bitmap in EaselJS. As everything is drawn in a HTML5 canvas, I can't use `document.getElementById('xx').style.visibility = 'hidden'`, or use the jQuery equivalent of `$('#xx').hide()`.

Any idea how I can go about this? I can't seem to find it in the [docs](http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/modules/EaselJS.html) either. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the property visible to false.

```
var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap("image.png");
bitmap.visible = false;
```